# Warning to make a cleanup function in useEffect() occurs occasionally

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify

I am using AWS-Amplify and when a user signs out I get a warning:

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
```

It mentions it occurs in the `Profile.tsx` file and this is the useEffect() hook.

But the issue is that the error occurs **sometimes**.

I keep testing it out and it comes and goes and I have no idea why it is so.

```
 function Profile() {

  const [user, setUser] = useState<IIntialState | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    checkUser();
    Hub.listen("auth", data => {
      const { payload } = data;
      if (payload.event === "signOut") {
        setUser(null);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  async function checkUser() {
    try {
      const data = await Auth.currentUserPoolUser();
      const userInfo = { username: data.username, ...data.attributes };
      console.log(userInfo);
      setUser(userInfo);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("error: ", err);
    }
  }
  function signOut() {
    Auth.signOut().catch(err => console.log("error signing out: ", err));
  }
  if (user) {
    return (
      <Container>
        <h1>Profile</h1>
        <h2>Username: {user.username}</h2>
        <h3>Email: {user.email}</h3>
        <h4>Phone: {user.phone_number}</h4>
        <Button onClick={signOut}>Sign Out</Button>
      </Container>
    );
  }
  return <Form setUser={setUser} />;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I happens because you component unmounts but you still have subscriptions in it.

**React useEffect** provides unmount function:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    Hub.listen("auth", func);
    return () => {
    // unsubscribe here
     Hub.remove("auth", signOut)
    };
 });
```

And you Hub Class has remove method

```
remove(channel: string | RegExp, listener: HubCallback): void
```

Remove your subscription in **useEffect** return function

[Hub.remove()](https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/api/classes/hubclass.html#remove)

Comment: Would I place ```Hub.remove()``` in the cleanup function? Also what would I have to pass in as the ```channel``` and ```listener```?

Comment: You have subscription on 'auth' Hub.listen("auth", func). Checkout your ws tab in network, the subscription should still exist onUnmount component. Try to unsubscribe from it Hub.remove('auth')

Comment: Also it could make memory leaks, each time you render your component you have new subscription, but you never unsubscribe

Comment: yes, out it in return function. Please check my update

Comment: ```remove()``` takes in 2 arguments.

Comment: the second arg is : listener: HubCallback - just put a function there

Comment: Alright it works with ```Hub.remove("auth", signOut)```. Edit the answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

`Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.`

The message is straightforward. We're trying to change the state of a component, even after it's been unmounted and unavailable.

There are multiple reasons why this can happen but the most common are that we didn’t unsubscribe to a websocket component, or this were dismount before an async operation finished. to solve this you can either do this :

```
 useEffect(() => {
    checkUser();
    //check howto remove this listner in aws documentation  
    const listner= Hub.listen("auth", data => {
      const { payload } = data;
      if (payload.event === "signOut") {
        setUser(null);
      }
    });

    //this return function is called on component unmount 
    return ()=>{/* romve the listner here */}
  }, []);
```

or go with this simple approach .

```
 useEffect(() => {
    let mounted =true
    Hub.listen("auth", data => {
      const { payload } = data;
      if (payload.event === "signOut" && mounted ) {
        setUser(null);
      }
    });


     //this return function is called on component unmount 
    return ()=>{mounted =false }
  }, []);
```

> Read more about [this here](https://dev.to/otamnitram/react-useeffect-cleanup-how-and-when-to-use-it-2hbm).

Comment: This works as well but I went with the other one as it was more suitable for my specific use case with AWS-Amplify.